# Object assignment error : Cannot set property "item" of undefined to "7723"

Tags: javascript, object

I am encountering an error -> Cannot set property "item" of undefined to "7723"

My code is as follows:

```
var objBins = new Object();

var stItem = "7723"
var stBinnumber = "S-1-77"

objBins[stItem + stBinnumber].item = stItem;
objBins[stItem + stBinnumber].binnumber = stBinnumber;
```

What does the error means? What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, when you access an element which is not there in the object, it will return `undefined`. So,

```
objBins[stItem+stBinnumber]
```

would give `undefined` and you are accessing `item` on it. That is why you are getting the error,

> Cannot set property "item" of undefined to "7723"

You should create the corresponding object first, like this

```
var objBins = new Object();
var stItem = "7723"
var stBinnumber = "S-1-77"
objBins[stItem + stBinnumber] = {};
```

Now, you have created an object with the key `7723S-1-77` and then you can do

```
objBins[stItem + stBinnumber].item = stItem;
objBins[stItem + stBinnumber].binnumber = stBinnumber;
```

If you print the `objBins` now, it would look like this

```
{ '7723S-1-77': { item: '7723', binnumber: 'S-1-77' } }
```

**Note:** You can always create a new object, with the object literal, like this

```
var objBins = {};
var stItem = "7723"
var stBinnumber = "S-1-77"
objBins[stItem + stBinnumber] = {
    item: stItem,
    binnumber: stBinnumber
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no object at the key `stItem + stBinnumber` therefore when you try to add the property `item` it produces the error `undefined`.

Set it to an object first, then add your `item` to that object.

```
objBins[stItem + stBinnumber] = {};

objBins[stItem+stBinnumber].item = stItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the `item` property on something that does not exist. You have not assigned anything to `objBins["7723S-1-77"]`, so it is `undefined`.

Instead, try:

```
var objBins = new Object();

var stItem                                  =   "7723"
var stBinnumber                             =   "S-1-77"            

objBins[stItem+stBinnumber] = {
    item: stItem,
    binnumber: stBinnumber
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var objBins = new Object();

     var stItem                                  =   "7723"
     var stBinnumber                             =   "S-1-77"            

     objBins[stItem+stBinnumber]=new Object();// create new object
     objBins[stItem+stBinnumber].item            =  stItem;
     objBins[stItem+stBinnumber].binnumber       =  stBinnumber;
     console.log( objBins[stItem+stBinnumber].item);

});
```